# How to convert lines on the basis of pattern?

Tags: regex, xml, text, notepad++, sublimetext3

I have data which I need to convert into pattern.
Input data is list seperated by something (as it's easy to find and replace) ex. comma

```
food,apple,10,10 
sweets,candy,20,20
```

I want to convert it to XML:

```
<Item>
    <Product type="food" name="apple" price"10" quantity="10">
</Item>
<Item>
    <Product type="sweets" name="candy" price"20" quantity="20">
</Item>
```

Comment: Search for `^(\w+),(\w+),(\w+),(\w+)$` and replace it with `<Item>\r\n    <Product type="$1" name="$2" price="$3" quantity="$4">\r\n</Item>` - or is there something tricky behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a **regular expression** find/replace:

Use the find Dialog, replace tab:

1. *Find What:* `^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^\r\n]*)(\R)*`
2. *Replace with:* `<Item>\5   <Product type="\1" name="\2" price="\3" quantity="\4"> \5</Item>\5`
3. check *Regular expression* in the lower left
4. press *Replace All*

Explanation:

- the find splices the string into the comma-separated parts and captures the 
  values in `\1` to `\5`
- `\5` captures the linebreak
- the replacement puts the captured values inside the XML-Node

Answer (score 1):

Replace: `(\w+),(\w+),(\w+),(\w+)`

with   : `<Item>\n <Product type="\1" name="\2" price="\3" quantity="\4">\n</Item>`

[Please check out this demo.](https://regex101.com/r/tH0rM0/1)